# Android ArrayAdapter Indexout of bounds exception

Tags: android

I'm using Android ArrayAdapter in my code, sometimes i see this error cropping up

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=-1 length=12
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)
at com.sample.search.AutoCompleteAdapter.getItem(AutoCompleteAdapter.java:29)
```

Why would the index ever be -1?

I populate the ArrayAdapter using

```
@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if(constraint != null) {
                    // A class that queries a web API, parses the data and returns an ArrayList<Symbol>
                    SymbolLookUp symLookUp = SymbolLookUp.getInstance();
                    try {
                        mData = symLookUp.getMatches(getContext(),constraint.toString());
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {}
                    // Now assign the values and count to the FilterResults object
                    filterResults.values = mData;
                    filterResults.count = mData.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults results) {
                if(results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return myFilter;
    }
```

And my getItem method is simply

```
@Override
    public String getItem(int index) {      
        return mData.get(index).getSuggestedText();     
    }
```

Comment: Check the logic of your code because I'm sure that sometimes it would be meeting a condition where index goes out of range of the array.

Comment: @prasant i'm getting this error but cant trace. could u help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Override
    public String getItem(int index) {   
        if(mData != null &&  mData.get(index) != null) {

        return mData.get(index).getSuggestedText();     
}
    }
```

**EDIT**

You have not put your All code so i can not exactly say that you may face problem in mData.get(index) or not ..

But if you face problem of mData.get(index) is index out of bound exception then try below code

```
@Override
        public String getItem(int index) {   
            if(mData != null &&  mData.size() >= index) {

            return mData.get(index).getSuggestedText();     
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wouldn't putting mData.get(index) in the if clause, result in Arrayindex out of bounds exception again?

Comment: ou have not put your All code so i can not exactly say that you may face problem in mData.get(index) or not .. but if you facing problem then you can check using above Edited code

Comment: @prasrob i think your "mData" varable has no element

Comment: I added the exact checking condition to prevent the error. But still i don't know what causes it.